# Displaying a pdf file located on a http server from mobile phone

Tags: java-me, mobile-website

I have some pdf files located on a http server:

Like:

> http://domain.com/files/file1.pdf
>
> http://domain.com/files/file1.pdf
>
> http://domain.com/files/file1.pdf

I need to display these files on a mobile application using **java me**.

I tried to display them by opening Google Docs Viewer with `platformRequest`. However it seems Google Docs Viewer uses **ajax** and many mobile browsers does not support it.

Is there an alternative for **"Google Docs Viewer"** for mobile devices ? Or is there a better solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have something can interpret the PDF on the phone, you may need to convert the PDF to images on the server for display purposes.

Comment: OK the only solution is to convert the pdf files to html (thumbnail images) Do you know a .net library to do this?

Comment: GhostScript can to convert PDF files to jpgs (I have a C# wrapper for this and will share it, just email me, address on profile page) Or you can use a commercial component for instance from Tall Components. (I think they also have a free thumbnailing component)